# Wildcard certificate still warns of cert

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ssl, svn, wildcard

I'm trying to get an SVN server up and running.  CentOS 6.4, apache 2.2.15.  More importantly, I need to have it running on https only.  So I figure that I'll get ssl running first, as I've already tested it on port 80, and SVN works the way I want it to.  So this is probably more apache-related than SVN.

In /etc/httpd/ssl, I have ..

intermediate.crt  wildcard.mycompany.com.crt  wildcard.mycompany.com.key

We bought a wildcard certificate from GeoTrust, and I downloaded the intermediate.crt from their website.  In /etc/httpd/httpd.conf, I have..

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin my.email@mycompany.com
        ServerName hostname.mycompany.com
        ErrorLog logs/error_log
        CustomLog logs/access_log common
        Redirect permanent / https://hostname.mycompany.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost hostname.mycompany.com:443>
        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/wildcard.mycompany.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/wildcard.mycompany.com.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/ssl/intermediate.crt
        ServerName hostname.mycompany.com
        ServerAdmin my.email@mycompany.com
        ErrorLog logs/subversion-error_log
        CustomLog logs/subversion-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

I can connect to the server, but my browser tells me that the certificate is untrusted.  So I'm guessing that there's an error in the permissions, or perhaps in the format of the file?

I can't see anything in the logs.

I set this up at home on my own server, but wasn't using a wildcard certificate.

Anyone care to advise as to what's gone wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Please consider either telling us the domain name, or posting the certificate and intermediate (**but not the keyfile!**) here.  It's hard to say what might be the issue with a certificate noone can see, and there are no security implications to making a certificate public - that's what it's for.

Comment: Were you connecting to the server using a name that's covered by the wildcard certificate?

Comment: maybe you download wrong GeoTrust intermediate.crt? They have 2 different bundles for certificates issued before and after June 13, 2013

Comment: If you run "openssl s_client -connect mycompany.com:443" from a Linux or Cygwin prompt, if should give you a bit more to go on..